# How to use 3-legged OAuth in Tweepy with Twitter API v2 to read protected Tweets?

Tags: python, oauth, tweepy, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python

I am trying to access protected Tweets from Twitter handles using Tweepy and Twitter API v2. To do this I know I have to use 3-legged OAuth. I have done it and successfully generated an access token and access token secret. But with those access keys I am not able to see the protected Tweets of my own protected account when I am authorizing with the same account.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

This is a **login.py** file with the authorization function

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tweepy 


def authrize():

    CONSUMER_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXxx"

    CONSUMER_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"

    BEARER_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,callback="oob")

    print(auth.get_authorization_url())

    verifier = input("Input PIN: ")
    ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = auth.get_access_token(verifier)

    print(ACCESS_TOKEN,"******",ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    return (CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,BEARER_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

and my tweepy code **app.py** is as follows

```
import tweepy
import login

def get_client(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,BEARER_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET):
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN,
                           consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
                           consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                           access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
                           access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    return client


def get_user_id(username):
    user = client.get_user(username=username)
    return user.data.id
    


def pagination(user_id):
    responses = tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, user_id,
                                 exclude='replies,retweets',
                                 max_results=100,
                                 expansions='referenced_tweets.id',
                                 tweet_fields=['created_at', 'public_metrics', 'entities'])
    return responses

def get_original_tweets(user_id):
    tweet_list = []
    responses = pagination(user_id)
    for response in responses:
        if response.data ==None:
            continue
        else:
            for tweets in response.data:
                tweet_list.append([tweets.text,
                                tweets['public_metrics']['like_count'],
                                tweets['public_metrics']['retweet_count'],
                                tweets['created_at'].date()])

    return tweet_list


def user_details(username):
    user = {}
    user_response = client.get_user(username=username, user_fields=['public_metrics', 'description', 'url'])
    user_metrics = user_response.data['public_metrics']
    user['description'] = user_response.data['description']
    user['followers'] = user_metrics['followers_count']
    user['following'] = user_metrics['following_count']
    return user

keys = login.authrize()
client = get_client(*keys)
username = input("Username:")
userid = get_user_id(username)
print(user_details(username))
print(get_original_tweets(userid))
```

Comment: Where does it state in the documentation that you would be able to see protected tweets?

Comment: If I am authorizing through my own account, I thought I should be able to see my own protected tweets.

Comment: I would check the documentation.    never assume anything.

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline   It says "User timelines belonging to protected users may only be requested when the authenticated user either "owns" the timeline or is an approved follower of the owner."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, [`Client.get_users_tweets`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_tweets) uses your bearer token rather than OAuth 1.0a User Context to authenticate. You need to set the `user_auth` parameter to `True`.